# Load xforms in php

Tags: php, html, xforms

I am trying to load a xform in php application. When i put this code in php view file and its not showing submit button in the UI. How can load xform xml in php applications?

```
<h:html xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
<h:head>
 <h:title>Search</h:title>
 <model>
  <submission action="http://example.com/search"
              method="post" id="s"/>
 </model>
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <h:p>
  <input ref="q"><label>Find</label></input>
  <submit submission="s"><label>Go</label></submit>
 </h:p>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

Answer (score 1):

XForms is not natively supported by browsers.

With PHP, it is not possible to use server-side implementations of XForms such as Orbeon or Betterform because they are written in Java.

You can give XSLTForms a try: it just require an XSLT 1.0 transformation which can be performed with PHP or directly by almost any browser, except for some limited mobile phones, using a processing instruction.

-Alain